# Redirect 301 of subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

There was a link example.com/shop/product-1

now link is example.com/newshop/product-1

I try to wtite htaccess rule to redirect from /shop/ to /newshop/

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)shop(.*)$ $1newshop$2 [QSA,L,R=301,NC]
```

Doesn't work. Where is mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following redirect

```
Redirect 301 /shop/ /newshop/
```

This will redirect /shop/.* to /newshop/.*

Comment: That's work! thank you! but i want to know why my Rule doesn't work?

Comment: Your rule's pattern and target are indentical, so i think its causing a Redirect loop.